# Next js 14 - prop drilling

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple question.

I'm using "**app folder**" in my Next js 14 project.

In the **layout.tsx** file (**can also be page.tsx**) I get data from the server side API and pass it to the child components using props. This gets annoying when there are many nested children components. In addition, I also need to type the data that I pass using props.

Yes, I know, if I make the same request on the server components, Next js does not send a new request, it pulls it from the cache. However, I can't do this because **my children components are on the client side**. How do you cope in such situations?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

I searched everywhere but couldn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: You can use context in the client component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a context to propagate data through your client components

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const SettingsContext = createContext<SettingsType>(DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

then declare the provider in your layout

```
/* 
  SettingService.index should return Promise<SettingsType> 
  to fix the type error
*/
const settings = await SettingService.index();

return (
  <html ...>
    <body ...>
     <ReactQueryProvider>
       <SettingsContext.Provider value={settings}>
         <MainLayout ...>
           {children}
         </MainLayout>
       </SettingsContext.Provider>
     </ReactQueryProvider>
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

and finally use this context in your client components

```
const settings = useContext(SettingsContext);
```

Comment: Thank very much. All data appears in the "page source" and I can access it in all client components. This is very easy.
Well, let's assume that I have 100 pages and they all consist of nested components in the same way. Is it appropriate to do this application for all pages? So let me wrap all the pages (page.tsx) in the Provider (ProductsContext, ProjectsContext, UserContext, etc...) like this.

Comment: it would be more appropriate to declare the provider juste once in `layout.tsx` instead of in 100 `page.tsx`